# php array of dictionaries

Tags: php, json

I have multiple functions inside my php that look like this

```
function linkExtractor($html){ 
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $last = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 
    $doc->loadHTML($html); 
    libxml_use_internal_errors($last); 
    $xp = new DOMXPath($doc); 
    
    $result = array(); 
    foreach ($xp->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' infaa ')]") as $node) 
        $result[] = trim($node->textContent); 
    return $result;     
}
```

And I am using this to turn them into json:

```
echo json_encode(array("info" => linkExtractor($html),
"dates" => linkExtractor2($html),
"names" => linkExtractor3($html),
"images" => linkExtractor4($html),
"genres" => linkExtractor5($html)
));
```

But this is returning the json like this:

```
{
"name":["melter",...],
"date":["05/24/14",...],
"image":["pictu.jpg",...],
"genre":["art",...],
"info":["Lorem ipsum",...]
}
```

I am looking to batch them so the first of each result is put into a curly brackets like this:

```
[ 
{ 
"name": "melter", 
"date": "05/24/14", 
"image": "pictu.jpg",
"genre": "art",
"info": "Lorem ipsum"
},
...
]
```

How can I do this?

---

## HTML snippet:

```
<table width="703" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<th width="697" scope="col">
<div id='gopro-hero-3'>
<a  href="Bits&Bobs/gopro-hero-3.html"><img src="pictu.jpg" alt="" width="700" height="525" class="images  gopro-hero-31" /></a>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="type" align="centre">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="right">
<tr>
<th width="48%" class="type genre" scope="col">art</th>
<th width="3%" class="" scope="col"> </th>
<th width="49%" class="date" scope="col">05/24/14</th>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<th class="name" align="left" scope="col"><a  class="gopro-hero-31" href="Bits&Bobs/gopro-hero-3.html">melter</a>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="infaa" align="left" scope="col">Lorem ipsum</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample of your DOM Document/XML?

Comment: Yes hold on! You mean a HTML snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the arrays returned by the linkextractor functions are the same length.

```
$arr = array();

$info = linkExtractor($html);
$dates = linkExtractor2($html);
$names = linkExtractor3($html);
$images = linkExtractor4($html);
$genres = linkExtractor5($html);

for ($i=0; $i<count($info); $i++) {
    $arr[] = array("info" => $info[$i], "date" => $dates[$i], "name" => $names[$i], "image" => $images[$i], "genre" => $genres[$i]);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each array has the same number of elements and assuming you extract them in the same order, you can loop like that:

```
$count = count($names);
$result = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$countà; ++$i) {
    $item = new stdClass;
    $item->name = $names[$i];
    $item->date = $dates[$i];
    // ...
    $result[] = $item;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

**However, what you are doing is highly inefficient and you should rethink your parsing strategy to extract all the information in a single pass.**